# The global attribute ... has already been declared

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I've been trying to add a menu to my app but i've ran into some trouble. since i'm pretty new to xamarin android i mostly copy/pasted the stuff from the internet. however changing my axml files has stopped working to change my Resource.Designer.cs file. so none of the elements in them can be found with the FindViewById<> method. this is my axml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <android.support.v7.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            app:menu="@MenuLayout"
            app:headerLayout="@Header" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="31.0dp"
            android:textSize="32dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TableLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
            android:weightSum="2" />
        <ListView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ListView" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

since i've copied most of the stuff from the internet i also needed to implement and download some stuff. Since i did this i have allot of "Warnings" in my program. i think these warnings are the reason that my Resource.Designer.cs does not get updated anymore. Here are some of the warnings i see :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The global attribute 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:accessibilityLiveRegion' has already been declared.    CardAppReal C:\Users\bfonta01\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CardAppReal\CardAppReal\Resources\layout\Main.axml  7   


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The global attribute 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:accessibilityTraversalAfter' has already been declared.    CardAppReal C:\Users\bfonta01\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CardAppReal\CardAppReal\Resources\layout\Main.axml  35  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The global attribute 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:accessibilityTraversalBefore' has already been declared.   CardAppReal C:\Users\bfonta01\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CardAppReal\CardAppReal\Resources\layout\Main.axml  55
```

if u need something more please do ask.

thanks for the help!

Bjorn

Answer (score 2):

Please note, this is out of my own experience with such warnings. These warnings seem to appear when using views from the Android Support Library. I've heard from colleagues that Android Studio doesn't have these problems, but using Xamarin in Visual Studio, they do appear. I am always able to fix this by just closing the .axml file where the warnings are coming from, and then building and deploying my project.

If you try to deploy and the build fails a few times, just wait a couple of seconds and then try to deploy again, it will work after some tries.

Comment: new problems now after doing this.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Message  Could not find schema information for the attribute 'package'.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:icon' attribute is not declared.

also my Resource.Designer.cs file still doesn't update

Comment: @BjornFontaine Which file is this warning coming from? Also, Resource.Designer.cs is built on compile, have you tried deleting it and rebuilding your solution to see if that fixes it?